# Creating a new file every time a programme is run in c

Tags: c, file

I'm creating a programme that writes the results of a questionnaire to a .txt file and wondered if there was any way to create a new file with a new name every time the programme was run?

```
 FILE *fp;
 fp = fopen("results.txt","w");
```

How can the file reults.txt be saved under a different name each time?

so ive done the below which lets a user save the name of their results.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

printf("Please enter a filename to save your results to\n");

    char c;
    FILE *fp;

    if (argc >= 2){
         fp = fopen(argv[1], "w");}

    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF)
    {
        putc(c, fp);
    }
```

but i get a core fault.

Comment: Test the value of `fp`, if it-s `NULL`, there is a problem. In this case, print the value of `argv[1]`

Answer (score 1):

Use the standard C function meant to be used for this very purpose.

> 7.21.4.4 The tmpnam function
>
> ```
> #include <stdio.h>
> char *tmpnam(char *s);
> ```
>
> The tmpnam function generates a string that is a valid file name and that is not the same
>   as the name of an existing file.

Notably, this family of functions have some security concerns addressed by CERT-C [here](https://wiki.sei.cmu.edu/confluence/display/c/FIO21-C.+Do+not+create+temporary+files+in+shared+directories). C11 provides safer versions called `tmpfile_s` and `tmpnam_s`, as part of the optional bounds-checking interface. But if your beginner-lever questionnaire program does not need commercial production quality protection against hackers, this shouldn't be a concern.

Comment: Consider adding an example use. Likely need `L_tmpnam`.

Comment: From [man](https://linux.die.net/man/3/tmpnam), `Never use this function. Use mkstemp(3) or tmpfile(3) instead.`

Comment: @Phantom - Problem - It gets deleted when the program ends!

Comment: @EdHeal With `tmpfile` ? Yes, I know, it was just to quote the man. I should have stop to the first sentence.

Comment: @Phantom I believe it refers to this issue https://wiki.sei.cmu.edu/confluence/display/c/FIO21-C.+Do+not+create+temporary+files+in+shared+directories. Nevertheless, that's a problem in the _implementation_, not in the function itself. There is nothing in the `tmpnam` function specification that makes it intrinsically unsafe. Don't blindly follow advise you don't understand. And don't assume that every application has the same security requirements either.

Answer (score -1):

There is many ways to do this.

- You can take the file name as an argument.
- You can get the process id (with `getpid()`), and add it to the end of the name.
- You can add an number at the end of the file and increment it each time the program is run (by looking into the directory)
- ...

Edit: 
Answer to your first edit

You only open the file if `argv < 2`, so what will append if `argv >= 2` ? What do you think will append when you do `putc(c, fp);` ?
If you want your program only run if there is enough arguments, check it at the beging, and exit if it's not ok, with a message to tell why it's not ok. :)

And, always check the return of functions like `fopen`, `malloc`,... To be sure everything is ok.

Comment: Could you please provide an example of how to do this?

Comment: Did you try to think about a way to do this, or at least did you do some research ?

Comment: No i have no clue about how i would do it, i like the sound of passing it as an argument

Comment: Great, so try it, and if you need look some tutorial to learn how to do it. And if you try and you don't succeed we are here to help you (but only if you tried) :)

Comment: Ive just edited the question to show what i have, could you please take a look and see what you think?

Comment: it still dosent work, i seem to get the core dump when the programme reaches the while loop

Comment: Did you read my edit ? If yes and if you changed your, make a new one in your post to show yourprogress

Comment: There is nothing in the question that indicates Linux or POSIX, so this answer is kind of irrelevant. There is no standard function called `getpid`.

Answer (score -1):

You can generate random number by using `rand()` function in C and append it to the filename at the end ! Or you can append currentmillis to your file name to get unique name every time ! Of course there are many ways of doing it !
Or `char *tmpnam(char *str);` can also be used!

Comment: You cannot guarantee that the filename + number will be unique